# How to capitalize first letter after period, question mark and exclamation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea, where I want every first letter in each sentence to be capitalized.

Now I have this:

```
evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function(a) {
    return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1);
});
```

And this goes in af function, where `evt.target` is the textarea, and the function is called on keyup.

It works great, except that it doesn't capitalize instantly.
If I write:

> Hey. i need some regular expression for this.

then the "I" will capitalize only when i put a period at the end of "this". I would like it to capitalize the "I" instantly after typing it, if it comes after an ". >whitespace<" or "! >whitespace<" or "? >whitespace<".

I tried googling a lot of stuff, but unfortunately, this regex stuff is too complicated for me. Could anyone write this correctly, with a quick explanation?

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/([!?.]\s+)([a-z])/g, function(m, $1, $2) {return $1+$2.toUpperCase();})`?

Comment: I recommend you www.regex101.com for regex testing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm late, but maybe somebody needs jQuery code for it.
That works for first sentence too.

```
$('input').on('input', function (evt) {
    var $this = $(evt.target),
        re = /(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g,
        val = $this.val().replace(re, function (m, $1, $2) {
            return $1 + $2.toUpperCase();
        });
    $this.val(val);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/oqg5o88u/1/

es6 update:

```
let re = /(^|[.!?]\s+)([a-z])/g;
$('input').on('input', function (evt) {
  let $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val().replace(re, (m, $1, $2) => $1 + $2.toUpperCase());
  $this.val(val);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chukanov/oqg5o88u/27/

Comment: Fantastic solution @AntonChukanov! Thanks a bunch!! :D
- now, what if I would like to add some exceptions? Fx "mht." or "bla." are danish abbreviations - is there anyway to implement an array of  exceptions where it should not capitalize? THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `/([!?.]\s+)([a-z])/g` regex and pass the match to the replace callback function to only upper the second capturing group:

```js
let log  = document.querySelector('#log'),
    test = document.querySelector('#test');

test.addEventListener('input', e => {
    log.innerHTML = e.target.value.replace(/([!?.]\s+)([a-z])/g, function(m, $1, $2) {
        return $1+$2.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' autofocus /><br />
<span id='log'></span>
```

*Pattern details*:

- `([!?.]\s+)` - Group 1 capturing a `!`, `?` or `.` and 1 or more whitespaces (NOTE that replacing `+` with `*`, zero or more whitespaces will be allowed)
- `([a-z])` - Group 2 capturing lowercase ASCII letters.